# android glide image loading low quality

Tags: android, kotlin, image-processing, android-glide

I am using Glide to load images from firebase storage to my imageView gallery using ViewPager and when resizing the image to fitXY to the imageView I get a low quality image.. I've tried many things and Glide different configurations but still no success., any suggestions?

my ImageView.xml:

```
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/empty_image"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

image loading in my ViewPagerAdapter:

```
         Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(imageList[position]).error(emptyImage)
                .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                .into(holder.binding.image)
```

Comment: Do the original image have a proper size on Firebase Storage?

Comment: @BogdanAndroid every image is saved to firebase storage with its original upload size (which may differ from my imageView size)